# No horizontal scroll bar in Firefox 12 with window minimized

Tags: css, firefox, scrollbar

I'm working on a client site and noticed I get no horizontal scroll bar in FF12 when I have the window in restore down mode (the button just to the left of the x). Has anyone else noticed this? I've searched on Google and on this board but haven't seen any direct references to this in FF12. I don't know that it will cause a problem at this point but I was wondering if it was a bug. IE9 and Chrome display this scroll bar on the same site. I'm working to add it to my CSS. Is it something developers need to add in FF, maybe all version? I'm still pretty new to web dev. Other client sites or ours have this scrollbar, but I wasn't in charge of the CSS for those projects so I don't know if it was added manually. I shouldn't need help with the CSS, I was just wondering if anyone else with FF12 sees this. Cheers!

Comment: @Radio, this is a place to learn and everyone is welcome as long as they can write a proper question.  That being said, I'm voting to close this question as there's no demo, no code to see, really nothing for us to do here.

Comment: @Sparky672 I've read the FAQ and apologize for not wording my question correctly. Even though it sounded wordy, I did ask a specific question about manually adding the scrollbar. It just got lost in my huge paragraph. The problem has since rectified itself. I do wish I had been given a chance to reword my question before it was closed.

Comment: You realize you always have the option to rework the question and then flag it for moderation attention, asking to reopen.  Keep in mind SO is not about asking _"are you also seeing this?"_ types of questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a firefox ticket for it. Have a look at

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=749699

F12 has problems with positions with big negative integers.

Answer (score 2):

We got the same problem. Our web application showed correctly the scrollbars with firefox 11.

We lost the scrollbars with firefox 12.

Setting "overflow:scroll" shows a part of the scrollbar, but it is deactivated. So it seems that firefox 12 doesn't recognize the box overflow anymore under certain circumstances.

Chrome and IE show correctly the scrollbars. So there must have been a change with firefox 12.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't see a scroll-bar - it probably means there is nothing to scroll.

Anyways. Turning this on, may help you:

```
html {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
img.style.top = "-9999999999px";
```

into this:

```
img.style.top = "-99999999px";
```

This is a bug on Firefox 12.